# button that is not related to form with onClick does not work in a form

Tags: javascript

I am puzzled a problem.

When  is inside a form.
it does not work.
this error happens.

> Uncaught TypeError: insert is not a function

However when it is outside the form.
it works well.

I would like to put the button with onclick=insert next to
[input type="text" id = "total" name="total"]

What should I do?

```html
<form method="post" action={{ route('gumit')}}>
    @csrf                
        <label for="Scotland" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('info') }}</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value = "{{$company->id}}" >                     
            <textarea type="textarea" class = "textarea" id="item" >Here is...</textarea>
                <br/>
                ：<input type="text" id = "cost" name="cost" value =""> 
                ：<input type="text" id = "total" name="total" value =""> 
                <input type="button" id="insert" class="button" value="BUTTON" onclick="insert()">
                <br/>
            <button type="submit" class="button">submit</button>
            <input type="button" id="b1" class="button" value="BUTTON" onclick="update()">
    </div>
</form>
            
<script>
   function update() {
   }
   function insert() {
   }
</script>
```

Comment: The button's `id` is also `insert`. Rename either the function or the button.

Comment: @ChrisG why would he do that?

Comment: @ChrisG  When I change the id of the button.then  it works. thanks

Comment: @FlashThunder Not sure how exactly it works but an `id` becomes a global variable so my guess is it overrides the function definition

Comment: @ChrisG DOM id is not present in any variable scope, it's just a DOM node with that id. That's why you can't use id directly, but you have to use `getElementById()`

Comment: @FlashThunder Not exactly sure we're talking about the same thing, but provided I'm reading you correctly, this shouldn't work (which it does): https://jsfiddle.net/gyabrncd/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try any of two things :

1. Try defining the script at the head of the HTML file. That should do the work.
2. Use document.querySelector("#b1") to get the button and then use onClick method on that

   let b1= document.querySelector("#b1");
   b1.onClick(()=>{
   //code for function
   })

Answer (score -1):

u should use an anchor as a button

[working js-demo](https://js-demo.com/index.php?ref=a345a3bfbfb9)

```
(function (document, window, undefined) {
  'use strict';
  
  // Buttons
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.js-button');   
  
  var displayContent = function (button, content) {
    if (content.classList.contains('active')) {
        // Hide content
        content.classList.remove('active');
        button.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
        content.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
      } else {
        // Show content
        content.classList.add('active');
        button.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
        content.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'false');
      }
  };
  
  [].forEach.call(buttons, function(button, index) {
    // Content var
    var content = button.nextElementSibling;
    
    // Set button attributes
    button.setAttribute('id', 'button-' + index);
    button.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
    button.setAttribute('aria-controls', 'content-' + index);
    
    // Set content attributes
    content.setAttribute('id', 'content-' + index);
    content.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');    
    content.setAttribute('aria-labelledby', 'button-' + index);
  
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
      displayContent(this, content);
      return false;
    }, false);
    
    button.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
      // Handle 'space' key
      if (event.which === 32) {
        event.preventDefault();
        displayContent(this, content);
      }
    }, false);
    
  });  
  
})(document, window);
```